# LitElement slot with appendChild not working

Tags: javascript, html, lit-element, lit-html

When I tried to append slot child on my component on LitElement, It doesn't work and didn't accept to create it.

```
render() {
    return html `<div class="wizard-container ${this.className}"></div>`;
  }

  firstUpdated() {
    let wizardContainer = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.wizard-container');
    for (let i = 0; i < this.steps; i++) {
      let slot = document.createElement('SLOT');
      slot.setAttribute('name', 'step_' + (i + 1))
      wizardContainer.appendChild(slot);
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I personally don't recommend you to create slots dynamically for a web component you can achieve it, you just need to keep the creation code in the render function

For example, you can create an array out of your `steps` variable and iterate it using the `map` function to create the slots like this:

```
render() {
  return html`<div class="wizard-container ${this.className}">
    ${Array.from({ length: this.steps }, (v, k) => k).map(
      item =>
        html`<slot name="step_${item}"><div>Default content ${item}</div></slot>`
    )}
  </div>`;
}
```

And then use your component like this:

```
<my-element steps="3">
  <div slot="step_1">Custom content</div>
</my-element>
```

Which would result in something like:

Default content 0
Custom content
Default content 2

[Here's a live demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/Z2s67HKehHpzyikrPUOS)

As for the reason why your previous code wasn't working like you expected, LitElement for the most part expects you to keep the code related to templating in the render function as anything you add using `appendChild` or similar DOM functions will get "deleted" the next time the component updates so you'd have to append it after every update by yourself

By adding the slots directly in the render method, you guarantee they don't get deleted in unexpected ways

Comment: Thanks for your support,Your answer is correct too, but the other one is more practical ans serve my needs.

Answer (score 3):

The  element—part of the Web Components technology suite—is a placeholder inside a web component that you can fill with your own markup, which lets you create separate DOM trees and present them together.

your code is correct but you wait for another behavior 
you wait spot elements in your DOM but  there is no spot will appear because   you didn't input any data in your spot 
 when you try to use spot in your commponent it will work correctly 
just try it

```
<element-details>
  <span slot="element-name">slot</span>
  <span slot="description">A placeholder inside a web
    component that users can fill with their own markup,
    with the effect of composing different DOM trees
    together.</span>
  <dl slot="attributes">
    <dt>name</dt>
    <dd>The name of the slot.</dd>
  </dl>
</element-details>
```